# Invalid filegroup 'Customers' specified

Tags: t-sql

i am creating a database with primary and secondary filegroups. however, when i use sys.filegroups, the secondary filegroups not listed. and also can not create any table under it. please help.

```
CREATE DATABASE [mydatabase] ON
PRIMARY 
(NAME = N'OrderEntryDB', FILENAME = N'C:\SQLData\OEDB.MDF'),
FILEGROUP Orders
(NAME = N'OrdersFG1', FILENAME = N'C:\SQLData\OEDB_Orders1.ndf'),
(NAME = N'OrdersFG2', FILENAME = N'C:\SQLData\OEDB_Orders2.ndf'),
FILEGROUP Customers
(NAME = N'CustFG1', FILENAME = N'C:\SQLData\OEDB_Cust1.ndf', 
SIZE = 5MB, MAXSIZE = 128GB, FILEGROWTH = 5MB)
LOG ON
(NAME = N'OrderEntrySBTLog', FILENAME = N'C:\SQLData\OEDBTLog.ldf');



SELECT * FROM sys.filegroups;

PRIMARY 1   FG  ROWS_FILEGROUP  1   0   NULL    NULL    0   0
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE cust(cid INT PRIMARY KEY, names varchar(32)) ON Customers;
```

> Invalid filegroup 'Customers' specified.

---

thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are creating the `Cust` table in the `mydatabase` database? It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating MyDatabase in the context of Master, most likely.

Try adding

USE MyDatabase

GO

before your select * and CREATE TABLE statements.  That will switch context to the correct database.

You could also use a three part name for your select.

SELECT * FROM MyDatabase.sys.filegroups